IEnumerable not working in Azure DevOps pipeline
I have a unit test using xUnit and is uisng net 472. The unit test is testing the Functions we made that is using IEnumerable.I have an assertion like this
adt.PatientVisitInformation.First().AssignedPatientLocation.Facility.Value.ShouldBe("Arundel");
The unit test just works fine when run in the visual studio but when run via pipeline it returns this error
Error Message:
   System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements
  Stack Trace:
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00010] in <69ada62907b24213a012734531df1db1>:0 
  at My.Products.HL7.Parser.UnitTests.Definitions.Messages.ADT_ATests.Decode_ADTAMessage (System.String ADT) [0x00321] in <36abcadd6a6a4eadb1f459337a2a48d7>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <d636f104d58046fd9b195699bcb1a744>:0 
  Failed My.Products.HL7.Parser.UnitTests.Definitions.Messages.ADT_ATests.Decode_ADTAMessage(ADT: "ADT^A01") [7 ms]

and my IEnumerable in pipeline just returns like this
System.Linq.Enumerable+<OfTypeIterator>d__32`1[My.Products.HL7.Parser.Definitions.Segments.PV1]

This is the command I use in pipeline
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'
          version: '8.x'  # Specify the .NET SDK version
          installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

      - task: UseDotNet@2
        inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'
          version: '6.0.x'  # Optional: If you need a .NET 6 SDK for any reason
          installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

      - script: dotnet nuget locals all --clear
        displayName: 'Clear NuGet caches'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
        inputs:
          command: 'restore'
          projects: '**Integrations/**/*.csproj'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Build Function - Custom Function'
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: '**Integrations/**/*.csproj'
          arguments: '/p:LogicAppFolder=Test-Interface-LogicApp\LogicApp-${{parameters.testInterface}}'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Test Custom Functions'
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: |
            **Integrations/**/*.UnitTests.csproj
          arguments: '--logger "console;verbosity=detailed"'
          publishTestResults: true

the vmImage I'm using is ubuntu-latest

On the pipeline runner, git replaced the \r\n windows line ending with just \n and the parser is sensitive to this. It thinks the message is one long line and is thus not finding the PV1 segment as expected.
I just install dos2unix and convert the file that contains the HL7 Message. Here's the pipeline script.
# install dos2unix for converting unix to dos
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Install dos2unix'
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo installing dos2unix
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y dos2unix

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Convert Files from Unix to DOS Format'
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo converting files from Unix to DOS format
        find **Integrations/**/*HL7.Parser.UnitTests -name '*.cs' -type f -exec unix2dos {} \;

